# SQL: how to compare date values within nvarchar datatypes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I build a query statement like this:

```
select * from men where Tdate between 01/01/01 and 02/02/02
```

The `Tdate` column is of type `nvarchar`

I am working with SQL Server Compact Edition (sqlCE)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  men 
WHERE
  CONVERT(DATETIME, Tdate) BETWEEN '01/01/01' and '02/02/02'
```

It depends on the date format and on the current [`DATEFORMAT` seting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189491.aspx) whether `CONVERT()` works or not.

It is advisable to convert the column to an actual DATETIME data type.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for a `CAST` or `CONVERT` statement in the WHERE clause on your `nvarchar` column.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Men 
WHERE CAST(Tdate AS Datetime) 
BETWEEN '01/01/09' and '02/02/09'
```

Here's a proof of concept:

```
declare @sample table
(
   TDate nvarchar(100)
)

Insert into @sample (TDate )  --yes, this INSERT work on SQL 2008 only :)
Values ('jan 1 2009'),('jan 10 2009'), ('feb 8 2009'),('feb 12 2009')

SELECT * 
FROM @sample 
WHERE CAST(Tdate AS Datetime) BETWEEN '01/01/09' AND '02/10/09'
```